# How put files into zip just for pack them and no compress them in Java

Tags: java, zip, compression, gzip

Is there way in Java to pack files into zip without compression? I just need to pack many files into one, but i need it fast and compression take long time. I tried something like Stored method of ZipOutputStream but the result zip is always corrupted.
Does anybody know some solution?

EDIT:
There is my code:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip"); // zip archive format
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, ContentDisposition.attachment()
                                                                            .filename("download.zip", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                                                            .build()
                                                                            .toString());
        
            response.setContentLengthLong(totalSize);
    
            try(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
                zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
            for (FileSystemResource file : resources) {
                try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
                    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getFilename().toString()));
                    StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, zipOutputStream);
                    zipOutputStream.flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

it works normal but when i added:

```
zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
```

i get this error when i try to open final zip:
Could not open, ERROR 1 process doesnt exist

Zip wihtou level is always good

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#setMethod(int)) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#STORED)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: since you are only sending a single file and seem to not want compression, why are you embedding the file in a zip file anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the content length of the response to (presumably) the length of the file you are outputting.  however, a zip file, even with no compression, still includes a header (or footer as the case may be).  you either have to compute the length of the *complete* zip file, or use chunked encoding.

Comment: This might explain why it works if compression is on - the total length of the zip file will be slightly greater than the original file if there is no compression, but smaller if there is compression. Without compression, the file will end up being truncated due to the setContentLength call. Try calling setContentLength at the end with the actual length of the zipped file/output stream.

Comment: yeah, that's what i expect as well.  you generally can't call setContentLength after you send the data, because that needs to be sent first as a header.  if the data is small, depending on the library you use, it may buffer it in member before sending.  but if it is large, you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: So i tested it and you have true. Its because setting little smaller size than final zip. The problem is, that my files are not so small to just pack it before and send, i would need it send inmedietly to response, but then i will not know size for my backend progress bar, i think i am lost :D

Comment: @Sizor that is what chunked encoding is for.  you don't have to know the size before sending.  alternately, you can skip the zip wrapper and just send the file directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION)`.

Answer (score 0):

The ZipOutputStream setLevel method is what you want. A value of '0' specifies no compression.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#setLevel-int-

EDIT: The best form is to use the deflator constant NO_COMPRESSION instead of 0.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#NO_COMPRESSION

Comment: Easier yes, but don't use magic numbers but [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#STORED) (or equiv.)

Comment: Quite right, the documentation for setLevel didn't link to the constants, but does document that the value is a number between 0 and 9. Anyway, here's the documentation on the 'NO_COMPRESSION' constant: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#NO_COMPRESSION

Comment: Look at my edited post, i tried setLevel but still have issues

Comment: If that utf-8 setting on the response applies to the file then you're going to be in trouble. The file will be corrupt